# How can I select a random string from an array and assign it to a variable?

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

For example

```
var names = array["bob","tom","jake"];
```

how could I select a random name from that array and assign it to the variable

```
var randomName = I don't know what goes here
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `Math.random` method.

```
var random=Math.floor((Math.random() * names.length));
var randomName=names[random];
```

Also, in `javascript` the arrays are declared like this :

```
var names = ["bob","tom","jake"];
```

not

```
var names = array["bob","tom","jake"];
```

```js
var names = ["bob","tom","jake"];
var random=  Math.floor((Math.random() * names.length));
var randomName=names[random];
console.log(randomName);
```

Comment: How does var random work?

Comment: @TheLegend27 It generates a random number between `0` and `names.length - 1`.

Comment: As @BenM said, it generates a random number from 0 and `names.length-1`

Comment: Why do you have to subtract 1?

Comment: Because array indexes are from 0.

Comment: In your case: "bob" has index 0, "tom" has index 1... If you have more elements in array, the last one has index `array.length-1`.

Comment: Oh ok I forgot about that

Comment: @TheLegend27, don't forget to accept answer in order to help other people.

Comment: my bad hope I can help people now

Answer (score 0):

Use *random* method

```
 var randomName = names[Math.floor(Math.random()*items.length)];
```